# How to import address line 2 field using Magento AvS_fastsimpleimporter

Tags: magento, import, avs

How can I import a customer's address line 2 using the AvS importer for Magento? The example shows only one line and the names do not match the Magento fields, so I'm not sure how to handle this.

```
$data = array(
array(
    'email' => 'customer@company.com',
    '_website' => 'base',
    'group_id' => 1,
    'firstname' => 'John',
    'lastname' => 'Doe',
    '_address_firstname' => 'John',
    '_address_lastname' => 'Doe',
    '_address_street' => 'Main Street 1',
    '_address_postcode' => '12345',
    '_address_city' => 'Springfield',
    '_address_country_id' => 'US',
    '_address_telephone' => '+1 2345 6789',
    '_address_default_billing_' => 1,
    '_address_default_shipping_' => 0,
));
```

I tried adding '_address_street2', but that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the \n (newline) in the _address_street field as divider between the first and second line.

```
...
'_address_street' => "Main Street\n1",
...
```

*Use double quotes for this entry in the array to have the \n be parsed as newline*

The result will be stored as provided in the database table customer_address_entity_text, which is in Magento terms a multiline field. For displaying it in the Magento front and backend Magento will automatically split it up by the newline and place this in separate input fields.

Comment: I suppose that would work, but I would really like it to go into the Address 2 field that Magento provides.

Comment: Gerard is correct; a new line is the correct way to do this in Magento. The second address line that you see in the Magento Admin and other forms is a bit misleading. Both the first and second lines of the address are concatenated with a newline into one attribute value, and stored in the customer_address_entity_text table.